# How to set environment variables in GAE with Java - not exposed in main code? Or other way to hide keys used by application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm developing a web-application on GAE with Java, and I'm going to open code of this web-application on Github.

But, I don't like to expose some API keys in the code. Thus I'm looking for a way to store some data that application can get, without showing this data in code of working application published on Github.

For example, this servlet  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/mailgun/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/mailgun/MailgunServlet.java gets API key using [System](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/?com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.html).getenv() and usually enviroment variables [written in appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables) Is there another way? To set environment variables from Google Developers Console or securely store and get them from GAE Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's done through external `.properties` file (and [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class). Say you have one for demo development, and one for production (also it's common to have third one, for tests). So you can upload development file into Github, and keep production config for yourself (also don't forget to add it into `.gitignore`).

Basically you'll have 3 files in your `resources` folder:

- `myapp.prod.properties`
- `myapp.dev.properties`
- `myapp.test.properties`

(naming schema is up to you, it could be just `prod.properties`, but at this case it can conflict with some file from a 3rd party lib).

There're a tutorial how to read such files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html and JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

You need something like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
String name;
if (SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development == SystemProperty.environment.value()) {
    name = "myapp.dev.properties";
} else {
    name = "myapp.prod.properties";
}
props.load(Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name));
```

Most Java web frameworks can do that for you automatically. For example in Spring take a look at Profiles, `@PropertySource` and `ConfigurableApplicationContext`